# How to get itemcount where child value is false with firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

**Edit**:I wrote a query that should return all items where ticked is true. I try to set the count of tickedItemsQuery but it tells me count is not an function. numChildren is also not a function. How can I set the count of the query?

```
exports.tickedBoxesCount = functions.database.ref('/listItems/{list_id}').onWrite(event => {
const ref = event.data.ref.parent;
const list_id = event.params.list_id;
const tickediItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild("ticked").equalTo(true)
admin.database().ref(`/lists/${list_id}/tickedCount`).set(tickediItemsQuery.count());
});
```

Comment: Iterate the children of the snapshot and look for the thing you want to count.  There's no API to "query" a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code *creates* a query:

```
const tickediItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild("ticked").equalTo(true)
```

Note that it does *not execute* the query, it merely defines it. So there's no way that you can know the number of matching children from merely this line.

To determine the count, you'll need to execute the query, and determine the number of children in the resulting snapshot:

```
return tickediItemsQuery.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  return admin.database().ref(`/lists/${list_id}/tickedCount`).set(snapshot.numChildren());
});
```

Note that I also added necessary `return` statements, to ensure the Cloud Functions knows when your (asynchronous) read and write operations are done.

Comment: I hit a quotum in cloud functions, I'll make sure to test it again today and let you know.